# How do i store a variable value to a file in new lines on ansible

Tags: ansible

I would like to store the variable value to a file in new lines format.

```
- set_fact:
    linked_dirs:   "{{ linked_dirs.stdout_lines | select('search',nfs_server) | list }}"

- debug:  var=linked_dirs

- shell:  echo -e "{{ linked_dirs }}\n" >> /tmp/test
  delegate_to:  localhost
```

cat /tmp/test

```
[u'/net/rchserver01/data/share2 linked with /var/tmp/test2', u'/net/rchserver01/data/share2 linked with /var/tmp/share2', u'/net/rchserver01/data/share1 linked with /var/share1']
```

Required Result:
cat /tmp/test

```
/net/rchserver01/data/share2 linked with /var/tmp/test2
/net/rchserver01/data/share2 linked with /var/tmp/share2
/net/rchserver01/data/share1 linked with /var/share1
```

Answer (score 1):

First, if you have a list, you have to `join()` the items together.

Second, to write a file, use the [copy module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/copy_module.html).

Replace the last task with something like this:

```
- name: Write linked_dirs file
  copy:
    content: "{{ linked_dirs | join('\n') }}"
    dest: /tmp/test
  delegate_to: localhost
```

Comment: You probably mean: `content: "{{ linked_dirs | join('\n') }}"`.

Comment: Absolutely, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a python style list with that echo. In case you need the values only, iterate over the elements using `with_items` and `echo`.